# HTML tag vs React Component Performance in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What if I Convert all html tag in react component 
such as html button: `<button type="button">Test </button>`
convert to react pure component

```
 export default function Button({type, text, onClick}) {
   return <button type={type} onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>
 }
```

and use it 1000 time. Is there any advantage in app performance ?

Comment: Sorry but is this a hypothetical or a real scenario?

Comment: obviously, In a react project we use many buttons and other html tags,
but the which method is better for application performance and size

Answer (score 0):

If you have any behavior in the button or html tag then you should create a separate component. Unless there is no need to create component and it would not effect in performance.

Comment: can you explain me, how ?  Thanks